# using setState after function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, setstate

i try it using `setState` after function in react, first run function , function finished after run `setState({example:'example1'})` , how i can do it,

click button run loaded Variable with `this.setState({loaded:false})`, I will do the function setstate after the runtime `this.setState({loaded:true})`, how can it be done with a technique, i will use other code

> 1. container = () => { return (Balabla)}   // is finish after 2.select
> 2. this.setState({loaded:true})

```
    export default class search extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);


            this.state = {
             loaded:true

            }
        }



    render(){
    return(
     <Loader loaded={this.state.loaded}/>
    {this.container()}

    )}
    }
```

Comment: Please improve grammar used in the question.

Comment: what are you trying to say exactly? where is your setStste()? is it inside container()? you need an click-event or something? can you be more specific

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. I also cannot see how you are using setState in your code. All I see is a constructor and a render method.

Comment: the responsibility is very simple, I will do the function setstate after the runtime

Answer (score 2):

Probably you're asking for this, If I'm not wrong. You need an `event-handler` (`onClick` here) to call your respective function which changes the state. And also if your function is a paramless function, you shouldn't use the `()` in `react` while calling it.

```
container = () => { this.setState({loaded:true})}

render(){
 return(
  <Loader loaded={this.state.loaded} onClick={this.container}/>
 )}
```

Comment: Where will I return to where the container function is command? container = () => { return (Balabla)} i callback return with container

Comment: use google translate to properly narrate your version and then come back. your sentence makings are horrendous!

Comment: first I will run the function and write the contents of the function(return(blabla))
, then I will setState another variable, why do not you understand